# Element not attached to DOM after dragging and dropping

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver, in which I am trying to drag and drop a column of a table. But as soon as i drag and drop the column I get an error "Element is no longer attached to the DOM".
Below is the code I have used for dragging and dropping the element

```
            WebElement draggable = objectIdentifierType(
                          objectIdentificationKeyword, objectValue);

            WebElement droppable = GetBrowserDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectData));                 
            /*WebElement droppable = objectIdentifierType(
                          objectIdentificationKeyword, objectValue);*/
            if (draggable != null) {
                   System.out.println(draggable.getText()+"Draged element");
                   System.out.println(droppable.getText()+"Droped element");
                   //System.out.println(droppable.getText());
                   new Actions(GetBrowserDriver.driver).dragAndDrop(
                                 draggable,droppable).build()
                                 .perform();

                    HTMLReport.bw.write("<script type='text/javascript'>addDetailRow('"
                            + GenericFunctions.testCaseName + "','"
                            + HTMLReport.testcaseTABLESNO() + "','\""
                            + "Drag Value: "
                            + draggable.getText()
                            + "','Drop Value \""
                            + droppable.getText()
                            + "\" ','"
                            + "','Passed' )</script>");
                   // new
                   // Actions(GetBrowserDriver.driver).dragAndDrop(draggable,
                                 // droppable);
                   String actualResult = "The Slider value is changed to the expected value.";
                   CreateExcel updatePassed = new CreateExcel();
                   updatePassed.updatePassedTestSteps(actualResult,
                                 expectedResult, objectData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, you changed the DOM with this action. You need to assign `draggable.getText()` and `droppable.getText()` strings
I'm not familiar with java so much, but I think this should work:

```
if (draggable != null) {
    String draggableText = draggable.getText();
    String droppableText = droppable.getText();
    //continue your code from here using new variables
```

PS Sorry for my bad English